# Selecting objects with specific key:value pair from dictionary

Tags: python-3.x, key-value, dictionary-comprehension

I want to pick all the objects that have a specific key:value pair in a dictionary.

For example: if I wanted the pairs "key":"x" from the following dictionary:

```
mydictionary =
    "1" : {
        "key" : "x",
        "key2" : "b",
    },
    "2" : {
        "key" : "y",
        "key2" : "b",
    },
    "3" : {
        "key" : "y",
        "key2" : "a",
    },
    "4" : {
        "key" : "x",
        "key2" : "b",
    }
```

The output would be objects "1" and "4".

This is a likely duplicate, but I couldn't find a similar problem despite searching.

Comment: it's not a valid dictionary

Answer (score 1, accepted):

something like this?

```
[k for k, v in mydictionary.items() if v['key'] == 'x']
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to enclose the dictionary with `{}`

```
In [164]: mydictionary
Out[164]:
{'1': {'key': 'x', 'key2': 'b'},
 '2': {'key': 'y', 'key2': 'b'},
 '3': {'key': 'y', 'key2': 'a'},
 '4': {'key': 'x', 'key2': 'b'}}

In [165]: {i:mydictionary[i] for i in mydictionary if mydictionary[i]["key"] == "x"}
Out[165]: {'1': {'key': 'x', 'key2': 'b'}, '4': {'key': 'x', 'key2': 'b'}}
```